# Unity: Track player movement with camera only when character reaches a certain point on the Y axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm currently working on a 2D platforming game using Unity. When the player jumps, I prevent the camera from following them in order to allow the player to see what is beneath them. However, I have a mechanic implemented that allows the player to perform a double jump when they grab an enemy, and this double jump makes the player jump past the boundary of the screen. I was wondering how I would go about getting the camera to smoothy follow the player only when they exit certain boundaries. I have basic code written that does this in a choppy way. I will include gifs to show how my game currently behaves, and an example of how I want it to behave.

Here is the code I have written in my camera controller:

```
  transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, 50, -100);

    if (player.position.y > 50)
    {

        transform.position = player.position - transform.forward * camDist + Vector3.up * playerHeight;

    }
```

Below is an embeded imgur gif of what my code does now:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/houedOV" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/houedOV"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and below here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/deg5yeq"><a href="//imgur.com/a/deg5yeq"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:UnityScript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a *deprecated scripting language* made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C#. Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the questions and tags in line with each other :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should moving camera from origin to destination instead of set camera to destination immediately (1 frame or 1 update called)

Try to set camera position with this code

```
void Update(){

   // ...  
   Vector2 destination = Vector2.zero; // your camera destination you expected
   float maxMoveDistance = 1; // maximum distance to move camera in each frame
   camera.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(camera.transform.position, destination, maxMoveDistance); // move camera to destination
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured out the answer to my own question!

It was as simple as this:

```
 void Update()
{
   

    if (player.position.y > 50)
    {

        
        transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y, -100);
    }

    else
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, 50, -100);

    }
```